# Javascript validation

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm hoping someone can help me with a bit of validation, I'm taking the value of a form input as a string. I need to validate this against a couple of rules, so it can become a table name. I can do them individually but I've no idea how to put it together. The input (tempName) needs to:

1. Have spaces replaced by underscores
2. Have no special characters
3. Be less than 25 characters

1.

```
    newName = tempName.replace(' ', '_')
```

2.

```
    var regex=/^[0-9A-Za-z]+$/; //^[a-zA-z]+$/

    if(regex.test(tempName)){
    tempName = newName
    return true;
    } 

    else {
    alert("Only letters + numbers allowed - no special characters or spaces.")
    return false;
    }
```

3.

```
    if (tempName.length < 25) {
    newName = tempName
     }

    else {
    newName = tempName.substr(0,25);    
    }
```

Apologies for asking something so simple but I haven't really worked with javascript properly for a few years and I'm having trouble with nested if statements and setting conditions.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the first two you can put together.

```
newName = tempName.replace(" ", "_").replace(/\W/g, "");
```

But then I'd check for the length of the remaining string after the replaces to make sure I don't get a index out of range.

```
if(newName.length > 25) {
   newName = newName.substring(0, 25);
}
```

Comment: Why are you replacing an instance of a valid string with an empty string and doing nothing if it's wrong? Correct that first one please.

Comment: Because he didn't ask to have anything done if the input didn't meet the criteria he asked to have it prepared to become a table name.

Comment: But look at what you're doing. You're replacing every valid string with nothing, for one thing, with this part: `.replace(/^[0-9A-Za-z]+$/g, "");` which is completely wrong. You're also performing the replacement *after* the spaces replacement, which won't work if the string contains spaces.

Comment: Sigh yes I see what you're saying, I simply copied his stuff and tried to reuse but I suppose it would be better not to try that.

Comment: What do you mean with "which won't work if the string contains spaces"

Comment: Ah, you fixed it. Thanks! (But what I meant was you used `[A-Za-z0-9]` before, and you replace spaces with underscores before the next replacement, so `[A-Za-z0-9]` won't match those underscores but `\w` or `\W` will do the job properly.)

Comment: I just glanced at what he had copied and pasted thinking it was [^a-zA-Z0-9_] and not what he had in the question.  sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 5):

```
if(/^\w{,25}$/.test(name = name.replace(/\s/g, '_'))) {
    // It's valid.
}
```

Is probably what you want.

**Edit:** If you want to truncate to 25 characters, it's:

```
if(/^\w+$/.test(name = name.replace(/\s/g, '_').substring(0, 25))) {
    // It's valid.
}
```

Comment: Does this set the string length to <=25? or does it just check to see if the string is <= 25?

Comment: @kasdega: Just does the check. I'll add a different one to fix issues, though.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I was learning something new about regex's

Comment: @kasdega: If you want an interesting trick there, it would be: `if(name = /^\w{,25}/.exec(name = name.replace(/\s/g, '_'))[0])`. Phew! Lot's of inline assignments

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need to drop most of that in a JavaScript function block.

```
function validateTableName(tempName)
{
var newName='';
your code here...
return newName;
}
```

HTH...

Comment: Why downvote my response? My answer is clear and concise. I will grant it is not as elegant, but it addressed the issue. Additionally, the @minitech response does not address the special characters problem.

Comment: For future reference, I can't get @lerted like that when I haven't posted here, I don't think. Anyways, the downvote is because that's not the question at all. Put together his code, and it doesn't work. And yes, my response does address both special characters problems, look closely.